# IE 11 / HTML5 / Datalist / Select item on tab keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I noticed a different behaviour in **IE 11 and e.g. Firefox 34 using HTML5 datalist** .
In Firefox, navigating through the items using arrow keys ist possible, on pressing tab-key, the currenty focused item gets selected.
In IE, navigating is possible the same way but to select an item it is neccessary to press enter-key.
For my application it is neccessary to implement the behaviour in Firefox.
I tried catching the keydown-event for pressing tab and then triggering a keydown-event using enter-keycode, but it's not working.
Has anybody an idea how to implement selecting element on pressing tab in IE?

Datalist is just implemented as normal

```
<input list="myDatalist">
<datalist id="myDatalist">
    <option value="Firefox"/>
    <option value="Chrome"/>
    <option value="Internet Explorer"/>
</datalist>
```

Small jfiddle: [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L7L37non/)
Try opening it in different Browsers and start playing with tab and enter, you'll see the difference.